# Interesting representation of elements of $(0, 1]$ as integer sequences

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, real-numbers

The MSE question [any real number between $0$ and $1$ is expressible as an (infinite) sum of particular fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581188/any-real-number-between-0-and-1-is-expressible-as-an-infinite-sum-of-parti/3581231#3581231) suggests an interesting representation of real numbers in the half-open interval $(0, 1]$ as non-decreasing sequences of integers greater than $1$. Namely for any $x \in (0, 1]$, there is a unique sequence $k_1, k_2, \ldots$ of integers with $1 < k_1 \le k_2 \le \ldots$, such that:
$$
x = {1 \over k_1} + {1 \over k_1k_2} + \cdots {1 \over k_1k_2\ldots k_n} + \ldots
$$
(see the answers to the other question for a proof of existence and uniqueness and a proof that $x$ is rational iff $k_n = k_{n+1}$ for all sufficiently large $n$). This is taken from exercise 44 at the the end of chapter III of Knopp's *Theory and Application of Infinite Series*.

This seems somewhat reminiscent of the continued fraction representation of a positive real and I was wondering if it had been investigated further. Does this representation have any applications? Or is it just a curiosity? I have computed the first few elements of the representation for $1/\sqrt{2}$, $1/\sqrt{3}$ and $1/\sqrt{5}$ and the resulting sequences don't appear in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org) (which may be evidence that the representation is just a curiosity). Any pointers to work on this will be gratefully appreciated.

For the record, for $1/\sqrt{2}$, $1/\sqrt{3}$ and $1/\sqrt{5}$ the representations begin as shown below:

$$
\begin{align*}
1/\sqrt{2}{:} &\quad 2, 3, 5, 5, 16, 18, 78, 102, 120, 144, 251, 363, \ldots\\
1/\sqrt{3}{:} &\quad 2, 7, 13, 13, 94, 108, 966, 1875, 1911, 5898, 16916, 4117323 \ldots \\
1/\sqrt{5}{:} &\quad 3, 3, 41, 46, 281, 316, 316, 2003, 6731, 6966, 7472, 17687 \ldots
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: This is related to [Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: good point. I should have thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: Ittay Weiss's [The real numbers - a survey of constructions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03467) mentions A. Knopfmacher & J. Knopfmacher’s construction of the reals using Engel’s theorem, alongside other constructions including one by a certain R. D. Arthan ...

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: thank you for that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from mathcounterexamples.net, I can answer my own question. This is the [Engel expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion#CITEREFKraaikampWu2004). That Wikipedia link contains several interesting references.